# Find and replace in output of command based on file contents

Tags: linux, find-and-replace, debian-wheezy, tail

I have a `tail -f` command reading a log containing IPs however I wish to replace these IPs with hostnames, I have the `dhcpd.leases` file available to the machine on which this is running.

I have been able to convert the `dhcp.leases` file into (maybe?) a more useable format:

```
10.0.0.1 Hostname1
10.0.0.2 Hostname2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the filename of the file you want to tail is `file` and the filename of the list is `list`. I also assume that the file `list` looks like:

```
10.0.0.1 Hostname1
10.0.0.2 Hostname2
```

Then use this:

```
tail -f file | while read l; do \
  while read i h; do l="${l//$i/$h}"; done <list; echo "$l"; \
done
```

- The `tail` command is piped to a while loop that reads the input line by line into the variable `$l`.
- Inside that while loop, there is another while loop that reads the file `list` line by line and replaces the values from `list` in the `$l` variable.
- Then the line is printed to stdout.